# PHP script fails part-way through when called from exec()

Tags: php

I have a parent PHP script that can be executed from a browser. This spawns a child process via `exec('/full/path/to/php -f /full/path/to/child_script.php args &> debug.log &')` then returns a response to the browser. The child process generates a bunch of PDF files using Plates and mPDF. When called via `exec` from the browser, the child script gets about 10%-20% of the way through creating PDFs, then mysteriously stops without any output except for whatever `echo` statements I may have put in for debugging purposes.

- the child script works when called from the CLI using the *exact* same command as used by the browser
- the `exec()` call works on my local machine and our QA server, just not in production
- safe mode is off
- I have `chmod 0777`'ed the child script and all the files/directories it operates on
- `display_errors`, `log_errors`, `track_errors` are all on
- `error_reporting = E_ALL | E_STRICT`
- `max_execution_time = 600`
- `exec` not in `disable_functions`
- called `set_time_limit(0)` in child script

I'm really stumped. What might be causing this? Or what further steps should I take to debug?

**UPDATE**

The problem is not with the call to `exec` (or `shell_exec`) itself, since I can call a parent script that then calls the main script via `exec` from the CLI. The problem only occurs when I try to execute via the web.

Comment: If its printing echo statements how do you know that it has stopped?

Comment: It stops generating the PDFs. Basically, it's a loop that executes 250+ times, generating one PDF per iteration. I'll get echo statements for the first 30-70 iterations at regular intervals, then nothing.

Comment: Personally, if I had to use `exec()` in a script I would make sure it wasn't accessible via a browser window and make it a cron job if applicable.

Comment: @the_pete, I'd rather do that, too, but my client wants to be able to submit this via the browser. Although if I can't get this working . . .

Comment: Have you tried `shell_exec` instead of `exec`? http://php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php There's also some more environmental variables to check on if you read through the examples.

Comment: @the_pete, I tried `shell_exec` and `system`, and unfortunately, both had the same results.

Comment: what is the timeout of your cli php? I bet it's 300 seconds or so and after that the process is killed

Comment: @Pinoniq, when I run from the CLI, the script takes about 7-10 minutes. However, when I run this from the web, the last debug message I get is consistently about 130 seconds after the first debug message. I have max_execution_time set to 600 in both php.ini and the child script. The hosting company did tell me there is a hard limit of 300 seconds, so you may be on the right track there. I'm currently seeing if they can help me debug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some of the comments were on the right track. After discussing this with my hosting company, it does appear that they are killing the script after 120 seconds CPU time. This is why I was not getting any time limit error messages from PHP and the real execution time was not consistent.

My solution will be to refactor this as a cron job, where the server allows longer limits. Thanks all for the suggestions.